# Sortable Table in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm trying to design a feature in Elm that parses data from Json then renders it in a sortable table.

Naturally, I'm using a decoder to store the Json data in a list of records; then in the view I convert the list of records to a list of Dicts because I'd like to iterate over the data in the grid. I'm also using a str list, columns, to give titles to the columns in the grid, to ensure that order in which data appears in the grid is customizable.

```elm
resourceDecoder : Decoder Resource
resourceDecoder =
    decode Resource
        |> required "year" int
        |> required "total_amount" string
        |> required "seq_type" string
        |> required "sent" bool
        |> required "parents_id" int
        |> required "month" int
        |> required "location_id" int
        |> required "child" childDecoder
        |> required "id" int
```

```elm
childDecoder : Decoder Child
childDecoder =
    decode Child
        |> required "firstname" string
        |> required "lastname" string
```

```elm
responseDecoder : Decoder (List Resource)
responseDecoder =
    Json.Decode.list resourceDecoder
```

```elm
recordToDict : Resource -> ResourceDict
        recordToDict record =
            Dict.fromList
                [ ( "Year", toString record.year )
                , ( "Total Amount", record.total_amount )
                , ( "Sequence Type", record.seq_type )
                , ( "Sent", toString record.sent )
                , ( "Parents", toString record.parents_id )
                , ( "Month", toString record.month )
                , ( "Location", toString record.location_id )
                , ( "Firstname", record.child.firstname )
                , ( "Lastname", record.child.lastname )
                , ( "id", toString record.id )
                ]
```

```elm
columnsData : List String
columnsData =
    [ "Firstname"
    , "Lastname"
    , "Year"
    , "Total Amount"
    , "Sequence Type"
    , "Sent"
    , "Parents"
    , "Month"
    , "Location"
    ]
```

Here's the problem: to my knowledge, it's not possible to sort a list of dicts by values for a key, so I have to sort the record entires for a value (eg, if I want to sort by the first name of children use:

```elm
List.sortBy (\r -> r.child.lastname) grid.resources
```

However, the column titles are strings, which aren't always identical to the record key (for example, for the field, r.child.lastname, the column title is 'Lastname'.) And anyway, my understanding is record keys must be called explicitly, so it wouldn't be possible to match column names to record keys.

I'd like to be able to click on the the table columns and have it sort by that field; e.g:

[image]

I hope what I've written is clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be super cool of you to provide the input and desired output

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by input and output in this context, but I've included an image.

Comment: Have you considered using https://github.com/evancz/elm-sortable-table which - as far as I can tell - provides exactly the functionality you want?

Comment: It seems you're not really able to add styles or forms, etc. to it. I'd like to be able to make it very customizable.

Comment: Is it possible to use the Mdl package with the sortable-table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about to keep the columnsData as a Dict of
key and title?
Then use the key to sort the List of Dict?

(I defined `Key` to clarify which `String` is key of the resource)

```elm
type alias Key = String
columnsData : Dict.Dict String Key
columnsData = Dict.fromList
    [ ("Firstname",     "firstName")
    , ("Lastname",      "lastName")
    , ("Year",          "year")
    , ("Total Amount",  "totalAmount")
    , ("Sequence Type", "seqType")
    , ("Sent",          "sent")
    , ("Parents",       "parents")
    , ("Month",         "month")
    , ("Location",      "location")
    ]

sort : Key -> List ResourceDict -> List ResourceDict
sort key dicts =
  let
    getVal dict = Maybe.withDefault "-" <| Dict.get key dict
  in List.sortBy getVal dicts
```

Comment: That did the trick! In fact, because the resources are already a dict, I didn't have to make the columns a dict, only a list of strings. But the sort function you suggest is exactly what I was looking for.